# Calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha \int^{\frac{1}{n^\beta}}_0 f(x)dx$ where $\beta > 0$ and $\beta > \alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

An exercise in the lecture notes asks to calculate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha \int^{\frac{1}{n^\beta}}_0 f(x)dx$$

where $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are real numbers with $\beta > 0$ and $\beta > \alpha$ for a function $f$ integrable on $[0,1]$.

But I am confused about how to do this for any arbitrary function $f$.

To get a sense, I tried to put $f(x)=1$ and I got $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\alpha-\beta}$ which evaluates to $0$ since $\alpha - \beta < 0$. Then I tried $f(x)=2x$ and got $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\alpha-2\beta}$ which again evaluates to $0$.

Is this the case for all such $f$, can you explain how to deal with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition if $f$ is (Riemann) integrable then $f$ is bounded; say $|f(t)|\le M$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Now $$\left|n^\alpha\int_0^{1/n^\beta}f(x)\,dx\right|
\le n^\alpha\int_0^{1/n^\beta}|f(x)|\,dx\le n^\alpha\int_0^{1/n^\beta}M\,dx\dots .$$